# VMR9 and EVR differs in contrast using "video player settings"

Tags: video, directshow, graphedit

When using YCbCr formats like YUY2 the contrast differs between VMR9 and EVR when the graphics card is set to use the "default player settings" (NVIDIA Control Panel). Notice the slightly lower contrast in the VMR9 video in the screen-shot below.

[image: Wildlife.wmv in GraphEdit using EVR and VMR9 renderer using "default player settings" on graphics card]
[image: "default player settings" in NVIDIA Control Panel]

It seems to me that EVR and VMR9, using the default GX-card setting, are interpreting YCbCr input or output differently; either Y:16-235 or full-range Y:0-255.

Note that by setting "Dynamic range" (to "full" or "limited") manually in the NVIDIA Control Panel, I get the same result in EVR/VMR9.

The questions are:

1. What is the explanation for this?
2. **But more importantly**, how can one control this programmatically for EVR (or VMR9) so that one doesn't have to rely on the Graphics-card settings on the user machine for the video to be displayed with the same contrast independent of the video renderer used.

---

Explanation of the "Dynamic range" setting in the NVIDIA Control Panel:
[image: Explanation of the "Dynamic range" setting]